# Use of undeclared Identifier "Scoring"

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void)Scoring
{
    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
    score.text = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"Score: %i", ScoreNumber];
}
```

I get a red error message that reads `use of undeclared identifier 'scoring'` I though I defined scoring in the 'game.h' but I am still getting an error.

I'm very new at this, thanks for any help!

Comment: On which line? Can you copy the actual error message from Xcode.

Comment: Did you #define something somewhere?  (There is nothing named `scoring` in the above code.)

Comment: Copy/paste into your question (press *edit* first) the actual error message and the 10 or so lines around that line number in your code.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998365/undeclared-identifier-viewdidload/21998922

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the case matches.

Scoring vs scoring